# What separates events such as festivals and tournaments from other events such as running and partying?

Tags: semantics, lexical-semantics

Events are widely defined as things that happen. Actions can take place, but objects cannot, so it would be natural to assume that all events are actions. However, there are many things that we call events that we do not call actions. For example, tournaments, festivals, and circuses are called events but not actions, while racing and battling are events and actions. They are also used differently.

> I went to the party.
>
> I went to the partying.*

What is it that separates tournaments and festivals from gerunds like racing and battling? I have considered that tournaments and festivals might better be described as situations where actions take place, but that would make them abstract objects, not events. I have tried looking into a dictionary, but it was not very helpful. For example, storms are events but not actions, but dictionaries make them seem like actions.

> [storm](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/storm?s=t) - a disturbance of the normal condition of the atmosphere, manifesting itself by winds of unusual force or direction, often accompanied by rain, snow, hail, thunder, and lightning, or flying sand or dust.
> [disturbance](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disturbance) - the act of disturbing

But the usages are different.

> An act of betrayal is bad.
>
> An act of storm is bad.*

Storms, festivals, tournaments, running and partying are all events, but the first three have different usages than the latter two. If you can go to festivals and tournaments but not running and partying, wouldn't that make them abstract objects instead since their definitions would be closer to "situations where things happen"?

Comment: Events are like funerals or weddings, but actions are like gerunds such as running and punching. I got this question from reading http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/events/. What puzzles me is how things that are not actions can still be said to occur. If we define some events such as funerals or parties as situations where you do a certain action, wouldn't that make them abstract objects rather than events?

Comment: You're mixing up the common meaning of "event" which is a thing you go to, and the technical linguistic meaning of something that happens.

Comment: So would defining an event as a situation be correct?

Comment: Also, how would you define that common meaning of "event"?

Answer (score 1):

An action is an event with an actor.  Events don't have to have actors.  If I explode a bomb, then I'm the actor in the explosion event.  But if the bomb goes off by itself, there's no actor, though the explosion is still an event.

Comment: Well, I would say that an explosion with no actor is still an action since actions are defined as "the bringing about of an alteration by force or through a natural agency." But what bugs me most is the difference between nouns that represent events and gerunds. For example, the difference between parties and partying and races and racing. There are also words like festivals and carnivals where actions make up part of it, but don't completely describe it.